# В чем заключается разница между [:] и .copy()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

Столкнулся с такой вот ситуацией, имея список:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Хочу получить его копию, сделав новую `переменную` уникальной, чтобы она не ссылалась на адрес старой. Знаю две конструкции, которые по сути делают одно и то же:

```
b = a[:]
```

и

```
b = a.copy()
```

Обе они верные, и дадут одинаковый результат, но **есть ли между ними принципиальные различия**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Метод `list.copy()` [появился в Python 3.3](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-July/022368.html). Причиной его появления было желание сделать синтаксис более читабельным и потому, что для других объектов, таких как `dict` и `set` метод `.copy()` уже существовал и было бы логично сделать его доступным также и для `list`.

Python обрабатывает данные вызовы по-разному - `a[:]` - обрабатывается при помощи `slice`, а `a.copy()` - при помощи вызова соответствующего метода:

```
In [50]: import dis

In [51]: dis.dis("a.copy()")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (copy)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In [52]: dis.dis("a[:]")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 BUILD_SLICE              2
              8 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

> Какой из них работает быстрее?

для 10.000.000 элементов:

```
In [47]: lst = list(range(10**7))

In [48]: %timeit lst[:]
119 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [49]: %timeit lst.copy()
119 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

для 10.000 элементов:

```
In [53]: lst = list(range(10**4))

In [54]: %timeit lst.copy()
44.1 µs ± 602 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [55]: %timeit lst[:]
45.6 µs ± 3.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

для 100 элементов:

```
In [62]: lst = list(range(100))

In [63]: %timeit lst.copy()
456 ns ± 19.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [64]: %timeit lst[:]
458 ns ± 22.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

т.е. по скорости работы они практически одинаковы.

> Какой синтаксис предпочтительнее?

Я считаю, что `a.copy()` более предпочтителен, т.к. является явным и понятным и кроме этого если вам придется заменить в коде список (`list`) на множество (`set`), то синтаксис использующий срез не сработает для множества.

---

**P.S.** Много полезной и сопутствующей информации можно найти в [ответах на похожий вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Очень хороший и развёрнутый ответ.